# Bootstrap 3 breakpoints doesnt work for mobile screens

Tags: css

```
     <!-- Product Popup View Start-->
        <div class="modal fade appointment_view" id="appointment_view">
            <div class="modal-dialog" style=" padding: 110px;
            /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
@media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
padding: 55px!important;
} ">
```

I wrote this code for bootstrap 3 modal but 55px property doesnt be read by mobile screen.on mobile screen, works 110px padding property, in other words.

how can I change phone screen padding property inline or with class?

its bootstrap modal.I am write below information for if you want to check the website.

the website is this : https://resimli.yedek.deniz-tasarim.site/

on homepage, below slider, there are 3 green information box.click the appointment now button.then, a modal will be opened.the modal has the padding issue.

the modal has close button at top-right corner.the button must be seemed for every screen.

also the modal must be had padding because mobile user can click the padding space areas to return homepage screen.

so, my issue is this.I hope you understand me and you will find a good solution.

thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't have `@media queries` inside `style` attribute, put it on CSS file or if you prefer, it can be added inside `<style>` tag. In both cases the media query is used in the same way like your example:

```css
.modal-dialog {
  /* Extra Small Devices, Phones */
  @media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    padding: 55px!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: can I use it inside <style> tags?  if I use in css file, can I use double pretty paranthesis? I mean @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) {
.mynewclassname {
padding: 55px!important;
}
}

also if you give me negative point please click up point button,

Comment: @Farukrıza I've updated the answer. take a look